# How do I migrate Process Automation Settings

Tags: metadata

How do I migrate setting or users on **Process automation settings -> Default workflow** users through package xml?

Upon deploying workflow it shows error -> you must specify a default workflow user for this sender type

I already set up this on the org and it working.

But, is there any possible way to set up this through metadata or package xml?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was misleading. At the moment this information does not seem to be available via APIs, check the following idea - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeL0UAJ/allow-default-workflow-user-assignment-from-any-of-the-apis

Comment: The default workflow user setting is an org-specific setting and not available as metadata that can be deployed using package XML. you may need to manually configure the default workflow user setting in the new org after deploying the workflow